# Layout default not found in joomla 3

Tags: components, backend, joomla3.2

I make a structure of back-end side of Joomla component.This component contain two things one text box and one editor.The component was successfully uploaded but when i click on this component at back-end side an error occur like:"Error
An error has occurred.
 500 Layout default not found
 Return to Control Panel" i check all my class name which is written in views folder,though I am not able to solve it.
 thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There was mistake in my initialization of default view in my controllers folder.